# one_hot always return different integer for the same word

Tags: tensorflow, keras, text

When I preprocess text using one_hot function like this:

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text import one_hot
onehot_repr=[one_hot(words,voc_size)for words in messages]
```

The function return different value for each word when I run it in new session, any solution?

For example in colab:
first session for "World" return 123
but when I re run in new session it return 134
I expect it return same value for each session